# the Emulator runs fine, but not my app

Tags: android-emulator

When I select Run | As Android app, the Emulator eventually displays and seems fine, except that my app does not run inside it. I get the err msg: "Failed to install WhereAreYou.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found"

Which device was not found? The emulator ran fine?

Comment: The emulator does not emulate an install process with a specific device. the problem with with either you computer, the device, or the IDE, but not with the app or the emulator.

Comment: The computer is brand new, the IDE, too (I just downloaded and installed the entire Android environment today - Java SDK, then Eclipse, then Android SDK, then ADT. What is the "device" the err msg is talking about?

Comment: Every other time I get an err msg "Emulator-arm.exe has stopped working"; the middle time, though, I got the above-mentioned behavior - the Emulator seemed fine, but my app didn't run.

Comment: OK, now this is really strange.

Wondering if it was because I was targeting Ice Cream Sandwich, I made an as-identical-as-possible small project targeting 2.3.3 / 10 / Gingerbread.

When I selected Run | As Android App from Eclipse, the "Video Source | Capture Source | Select a Video Device" was invoked...????

Comment: Maybe I'm expecting the wrong thing - I'm expecting my app to show up after awhile in the emulator (with its cheery "hello world" type of message. Do I need to do something else to get it to display?

Comment: And, is mashing the "Close" (X) in the NE corner of the emulator the preferred way to dismiss it?

Comment: Is there anything displayed on the emulator screen at all?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a normal Android screen

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if there were some clear and straightforward way of getting this to run without having to be reasonably skilled in Android development.

Anyway I downloaded the installer_r15-windows.exe as recommended and ran that installer.
Then from Eclipse "ADT Plugin for Eclipse"

First thing then was to go into Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS and set the "ADB connection time out(ms)": to 500000

It also seems to help greatly to use the AVD Manager (from Window menu) to start the emulator.  And randomly go to the platform-tools directory and execute "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server".
Then in Eclipse use "Run As -> Android Application" from context menu and hopefully you get the following:

> ```
> [2011-11-01 12:28:50 - HelloWorldProj] ------------------------------   
> [2011-11-01 12:28:50 - HelloWorldProj] Android Launch! 
> [2011-11-01 12:28:50 - HelloWorldProj] adb is running normally.   
> [2011-11-01 12:28:50 - HelloWorldProj] Performing my.pack.age.name.HelloWorldProjActivity activity launch
> [2011-11-01 12:28:53 - HelloWorldProj] Uploading HelloWorldProj.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'     
> [2011-11-01 12:28:54 - HelloWorldProj] Installing HelloWorldProj.apk...   
> [2011-11-01 12:30:09 - HelloWorldProj] Success!   
> [2011-11-01 12:30:10 - HelloWorldProj] Starting activity my.pack.age.name.HelloWorldProjActivity on device emulator-5554  
> [2011-11-01 12:30:17 - HelloWorldProj] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=my.pack.age.name/.HelloWorldProjActivity }
> ```

Then wait a while and your message final appears in the emulator!

But if it is so difficult to run a simple HelloWorld app, is it worth perservering with Android?

Comment: Well, there are a gazillion Android apps in the Android Market, so I'm thinking it must be me that is the problem (I'm a doofus)